# Order results by COUNT without GROUP BY

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table and data like this:

```
ID | Name  | Group
1  | Apple | A
2  | Boy   | A
3  | Cat   | B
4  | Dog   | C
5  | Elep  | C
6  | Fish  | C
```

and I wish to order it according to the count of items in group from smallest to largest value, such as: B - 1 record, A - 2 records, C - 3 records, so it will become:

```
ID | Name  | Group
3  | Cat   | B
1  | Apple | A
2  | Boy   | A
4  | Dog   | C
5  | Elep  | C
6  | Fish  | C
```

I tried:

```php
$sql = "SELECT ID, Name
    FROM table
    ORDER BY COUNT(Group)";
```

but it just returns one result for me.

How do I order the data as described?

Comment: The accepted answer does not match the specified result (i.e. return all rows instead of one per group and all columns instead of those listed in group by). Only [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53212180/87015) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77935601/87015) address the question properly.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

You need to aggregate the data first, this can be done using the GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT Group, COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY Group
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

The DESC keyword allows you to show the highest count first, ORDER BY by default orders in ascending order which would show the lowest count first.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer , but it return me one result per group only? such as : Cat,B | Apple , A | Dog , C

Comment: Are you running this code or some other code?

Based on the first table you provided the output of this query would be:

C 3
A 2
B 1

Comment: You should prefer to use count(1) instead of count(*) I guess

Answer (score 16):

...none of the other answers seem to do what the asker asked.

For table named 'things' with column 'group':

```
SELECT
  things.*, counter.count
FROM
  things
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    things.group, count(things.group) as count
  FROM
    things
  GROUP BY
    things.group
) counter ON counter.group = things.group
ORDER BY
  counter.count ASC;
```

which gives:

```
id | name  | group | count 
---------------------------
3  | Cat   | B     | 1
1  | Apple | A     | 2
2  | Boy   | A     | 2
4  | Dog   | C     | 3
5  | Elep  | C     | 3
6  | Fish  | C     | 3
```

Comment: beautiful solution to the problem.

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed the only answer that meets the requirements.

Comment: One enhancement: Also add 'group' to the ORDER BY, so if two groups have the same number of rows, their rows won't mix with each other.

Answer (score 13):

```sql
SELECT group, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY group ORDER BY group
```

or to order by the count

```sql
SELECT group, COUNT(*) AS count FROM table GROUP BY group ORDER BY count DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
SELECT count(*),group FROM table GROUP BY group ORDER BY group
```

to order by count descending do

```
SELECT count(*),group FROM table GROUP BY group ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

This will group the results by the `group` column returning the `group` and the `count` and will return the order in `group` order

Comment: Thanks for your asnwer , I tried it but it return me one result per group ? such as : Cat,B | Apple , A | Dog , C .

Comment: @IreneLing I didnt include the Name in the select statement - check it

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table 
group by `Group`
ORDER BY COUNT(Group)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using below Query:

```
SELECT
    GROUP,
    COUNT(*) AS Total_Count
FROM
    TABLE
GROUP BY
    GROUP
ORDER BY
    Total_Count DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Below gives me opposite of what you have. (Notice Group column)

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    myTable
GROUP BY
    Group_value,
    ID
ORDER BY
    count(Group_value)
```

Let me know if this is fine with you...

I am trying to get what you want too...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sorry it didn't give me the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Q. List the name of each show, and the number of different times it has been held.
List the show which has been held most often first.

```
event_id show_id event_name judge_id
0101    01  Dressage        01
0102    01  Jumping         02
0103    01  Led in          01
0201    02  Led in          02
0301    03  Led in          01
0401    04  Dressage        04
0501    05  Dressage        01
0502    05  Flag and Pole   02
```

Ans:

```
select event_name, count(show_id) as held_times from event 
group by event_name 
order by count(show_id) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `count(*) over ()` inside `order by` clause:

```sql
select *
from t
order by count(*) over (partition by `group`)
```

Notice that there is no `group by` which means you have access to all rows and columns.

[Demo on DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GIg_ka3v)