# RoR top100 photos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I must create  page with top100 photos by visits, by comments... but i dont know how to make it. Anybody help me please :)

Error:

```
 undefined method `Visit' for <Photo::ActiveRecord
```

photos_controller

```
....
def top100
    @photos = Photo.all 
     @photos.visit.count(limit: 10)
  end
```

routes

```
 get 'photos/top100'
```

schema

```
  create_table "visits", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "photo_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "count",      default: 0
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

create_table "photos", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "image"
    t.string   "tags"
    t.string   "camera"
    t.string   "lens"
    t.hstore   "settings"
    t.integer  "im_rating",       default: 0
    t.integer  "im_visits",       default: 0
    t.integer  "im_votes",        default: 0
    t.boolean  "is_ban_comments", default: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

photo.rb

```
  has_many :visits, dependent: :destroy
```

visit.rb

```
    belongs_to :photo
    belongs_to :user
```

Comment: What were you expecting to get with this line `@photos.visit.count(limit: 10)`?

Comment: I understand you... but i dont know how to realise best way for my trouble... Could you help me?  I must show top 100 photos with best ratings by visits or by votes...

Answer (score -2):

Use SQL grouping and ordering:

```
# Top photos by visits
@top_photos = Visit.select("photo_id, COUNT(*) AS visit_count").includes(:photo).group(:photo_id).order("visit_count DESC").map(&:photo)
```

More on ordering by count in SQL: [SQL Order By Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545637/sql-order-by-count)

Notice `#includes(:photo)` – that way the following `#map(&:photo)` call won't produce N queries (just a single one to fetch them all).

Additionally, it seems you didn't specify relationship in your models, so add this line to `visit.rb`:

```
belongs_to :photo
```

and this line to `photo.rb`

```
has_many :visits
```

unles you have them there already.

Comment: The problem lays here `.map(&:photo)`

Comment: @Glupo Now you happy?

Comment: You were right bout my answer, @EugZol, I missed the `user_id` column in `visits` and that is why it was not making sense, so I assumed...

Comment: @RubyRacer Yeah, sorry for being too sarcastic, I was just too disturbed with the fact of receiving too much downvotes for no apparent reason. But now I'm fine :D

Comment: Why apologize? Is there anything wrong with being sarcastic?