# Sorting foreign keys by number of appearances (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database that consists of three tables, one for Movies (id, plot, length etc) and one for Genres (id, name). The third table, Movie2Genre, consists of FOREIGN KEY's so that I am able to link a Movie with a certain Genre (idMovie, idGenre).

Then I use the following sql to list each active genre:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT G.name
    FROM Genre AS G
        INNER JOIN Movie2Genre AS M2G
            ON G.id = M2G.idGenre
            ORDER BY G.name
```

But instead of sorting them by G.name, I would like to order them by which genre that is linked to a movie the most times.

If there are **3** movies that are linked to the genre **Drama**, **2** movies that are linked to **Thriller** and only **1** that is linked **Comedy** - I would like them to be ordered as:

1. Drama
2. Thriller
3. Comedy

Anyone out there that can help me?

Comment: For what reason am I getting down-voted?..

Comment: [Order By Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545637/sql-order-by-count)

Comment: Thank you Serpiton, I shall read it thoroughly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Order by Count was my first clue, provided by the user Serpiton. But my case was a bit different from the one provided in the link. With the help of a sub query I was able to get the result I was looking for.

The following SQL solved my problem:

```
SELECT G.name, M2G.totalCount AS tCount
FROM Genre AS G
 LEFT JOIN
 (
  SELECT `idGenre`, COUNT(*) AS totalCount 
  FROM `Movie2Genre`
  GROUP BY `idGenre`
 ) M2G ON G.`id` = M2G.`idGenre`
ORDER BY tCount DESC
```