# SQL order by count in an optimal way

Tags: mysql, count, sql-order-by

When we have to print the count of a table while doing order by the count itself, is the below query optimal-

```
SELECT Group, COUNT( * )
FROM table
GROUP BY Group
ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC
```

I am thinking that the `order by count(*)` would do a count and then the select would also do the count. Does MySQL optimize this query so that count is done only once?

I was looking at [SQL Order By Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545637/sql-order-by-count) when I thought if there was a better solution possible.

Comment: The order by is executed on query result  .. so the query is execute just once

Comment: If instead of COUNT(*) you count by a key column, like COUNT(id) is much faster

Comment: Group is a reserved word - your query won't syntax and is therefore very sub-optimal , if you really have a column called group you should enclose it in backticks or if possible rename it.