# SQL query to find districts by search volume

Tags: sql

Write an SQL query that ranks districts by search volume (if the search was for more than one district then each
value in the list is counted as one search)

[image]

Comment: how cn i add file?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Kb521qUBEU0mPD0vIFLXTGGVTfhKxd1zMr95CCOr6D4/edit#gid=1094332359

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments and do not link to external files for sample data)

Comment: any can be used, i have attached the excel file as link in comment

Comment: i have added data as image too. please help

Comment: but search by volume is not there in your excel?

Comment: yes, so search by volume means search how many times district 1 came then district02 came , have to taker count

Comment: did you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9545657/6108882

Comment: how should i imply this

Comment: try to do comma separated value as new row after that try above method it will works. Is your final result could be for eg: dist 1 - 20, dist2 -30...

Comment: so you mean my first query will be SELECT search_id, search_location
FROM searches
 CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(search_location, ',')

Comment: try the below answer it will works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first split the location by comma and insert into new row

```
;WITH tmp(search_id, search_location, Location, String) AS
(
    SELECT
        search_id,
        search_location,
        LEFT(String, CHARINDEX(',', String + ',') - 1),
        STUFF(String, 1, CHARINDEX(',', String + ','), '')
    FROM YourTable
    UNION all

    SELECT
        search_id,
        search_location,
        LEFT(String, CHARINDEX(',', String + ',') - 1),
        STUFF(String, 1, CHARINDEX(',', String + ','), '')
    FROM tmp
    WHERE
        String > ''
)

SELECT
    search_id,
    search_location,
    Location
into #temp
FROM tmp
```

from the above table you can get count

```
SELECT Location, COUNT(*) as [District Count]
FROM #temp
GROUP BY Location
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: wow! awesome dude , i ltry this in sql and respond with desired result. Meanwhile can you help me with ----- Which district had the highest day-on-day percent change in search volume and when did it occur?

Comment: i want to know the district which is highly searched in search location column so that i can compare the data searched on day to day basis

Comment: use this for max search location `select top 1 Location, count(Location) as [Max Count] from #temp
group by Location
order by count(Location) desc`

Comment: so you mean at first i have to split it as previous and then user top location, but how to gve day on day percent change- v2=v2-v1/v1*100

Comment: @AyeshaSingh where is percent change in your excel? where is v2=v2-v1/v1*100 in your excel... I'm not understand

Comment: it is not there, but when they ask find highest day on day percent change , doesnt it mean we search the highest searched district and then give percent using this formula

Comment: okay can you help me with - We want to drive conversions in the form of enquiries, what recommendations would you make to the Product
Team?

Comment: you can get highest search district from temp table from there you have to do percentage calculation. Product team means is this manufacture based? And If the above answer is helpful mark the right mark as answer.